# Axios Request failed with status code 404 - React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, post, axios

I am trying to send data to my Google Cloud server. (login form). I have an error,

> [Error: Request failed with status code 404]

I also tried fetch method, but I got a network failed error there.

This is my code:

```
handleLoginUser(){
const data = new FormData();
  data.append('email', 'aaykgxr@gmail.com');
  data.append('password', '1234567890');

  return axios.post('http://*serverip*/users/login',
    data,
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    },
  )
  .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
      });
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I guess it's proxy issues. can you please check proxies please.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The status code 404, means that the address does not exists. Are you sure that you are hitting the right route ? [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Answer (score 0):

You should use some other content-type if you use formdata:

```
'Content-type':'multipart/form-data'
```

Answer (score -1):

'http://*serverip*/users/login.json()....dot json() is missing

Comment: Considering that the URL is targeted by a Ajax POST call, it simply can't be a static json document.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thank you for your time in answering this question. Can you please give more details about your solution? Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).